# Getting value as undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to manipulate `value` of a button in JS from HTML.

HTML Code:

```
<div onclick= "classToggle()" type="button" id="show-more">Show more</div>
```

The output I'm getting for `elem` is undefined.

JS Code:

```
function classToggle() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('show-more').value;
    alert(elem);
    if (elem.value == "Show more") elem.value = "Show less";
    else elem.value = "Show more"; }
```

Comment: Remove `.value` from your 2nd line.

Comment: DIVs do not have a value property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `value` of a `div` which is not possible. In order to get the text in it, you should be using `innerHTML` as follows:

```js
function classToggle() {
     var elem = document.getElementById('show-more');
     alert(elem.innerHTML);
     if (elem.innerHTML == "Show more") 
          elem.innerHTML = "Show less";
     else 
          elem.innerHTML = "Show more"; 
}
```

```html
<div onclick= "classToggle()" type="button" id="show-more">Show more</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML instead of value

```js
function classToggle() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('show-more');
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
    if (elem.innerHTML == "Show more") elem.innerHTML= "Show less";
    else elem.innerHTML = "Show more"; }
```

```html
<div onclick= "classToggle()" type="button" id="show-more">Show more</div>
```